# Как сравнить две структуры с помощью BOOST, C++

Tags: c++, boost

При сравнение с помощью BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL выводит ошибку:

> error C2679: бинарный "<<": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "const Point" (или приемлемое преобразование

```
void IsPointsEqual(const Point &point1, const Point &point2)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(point1, point2);
}
```

Comment: или же сравнивать поля, структуры

Comment: Вы уверены, что говорится об операторе <<, а не об операторе <?

Comment: Сравните point1.x и point2.x по x и y соответственно

Comment: А у вас точно Функция сравнения? Почему она возвращает **void**? И что делает BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL?

Comment: Мне кажется что правильно бы было так: `bool IsPointsEqual(const Point &point1, const Point &point2){ return *(long*)&point1 == *(long*)&point2;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как следует из сообщения, вы должны определить для вашей структуры `Point` лператор `operator <<`.

Например,

```
std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Point &p )
{
    return os << p.x << ' ' << p.y;
}
```

Как на самом деле будет опредеен этот оператор, это уже зависит от вас самих. Я лишь предположил, что структура имеет два члена данных `x` и `y`.

На самом деле лучше не пользоваться для этих целей данным средством `Boost`, а просто сами определите операторы `operator ==` и  `operator <`. Этих двух операторов вполне достаточно для других видов сравнений.

Например,

```
bool operator ==( const Point &p1, const Point &p2 )
{
    return p1.x == p2.x && p1.y == p2.y;
}
```

Если члены структуры закрытые, то объявите эти операторы дружественными функциями структуры.